# How can I POST text starting with @ as well as upload file with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP and cURL to POST to the Twitter API. A lot of times, I include image data in the post and the text of the tweet starts with "@" to mention somebody.

Example code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'status'  => '@sampletwitter check out this image',
    'media[]' => '@/tmp/file.jpg'
));
```

The problem is that it seems to be attempting to upload a file in the 'status' field as well as the 'media[]' field.

I need to pass this as an array since I am attempting to do a file upload for part of it. How can I suppress the attempt at doing an upload from the 'status' field?

Answer (score 0):

simply, [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) the status field.

```
urlencode('@'); // %40
```